# Partitioning in window functions with same value in different chunk of rows

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

In the picture below you can example data. I would like to get first occurence of *batch_start* for each *batch*. As you can see (green highlight) batch 1522049 occurs in 2 chunks, one has 2 rows and second has 1 row.

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(batch_start) OVER (PARTITION BY batch ORDER BY batch_start)
```

does not solve the problem, since it joins both chunks into one and result is '2013-01-29 10:27:23' for both of them.

Any idea how to distinguish these rows and get *batch_start* of each chunk of data?

[image: Example data]

Comment: what is your screenshot order by column?..

Comment: @VaoTsun It's ordered by _batch_start_

Comment: there was a very similar question recently - let me look for it

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me a simple [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem: you just need to calculate a value, which is the same for every subsequent rows for the same `batch` value, which will be

```
row_number() over (order by batch_start) - row_number() over (partition by batch order by batch_start)
```

From this, the solution depends on what do you want to do with these "batch groups". F.ex. here is a variant, which will aggregate them, to find out which is the first `batch_start`:

```
select   batch, min(batch_start)
from     (select *, row_number() over (order by batch_start) -
                    row_number() over (partition by batch order by batch_start) batch_number
          from   batches) b
group by batch, batch_number
```

http://rextester.com/XLX80303

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: select batch, min(batch_start) firstOccurance, max(batch_start) lastOccurance from yourTable group by batch

or try (keeping your part of query): 
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(a.batch_start) OVER (PARTITION BY a.batch ORDER BY a.batch_start) from yourTable a
join (select batch, min(batch_start) firstOccurance, max(batch_end) lastOccurance from yourTable group by batch) b on a.batch = b.batch

Comment: eventually add the layout_name column to your select and group by clauses (as above or in the joined a+b part.